# ng-packagr warning:'defaultsDeep' is not exported by 'node_modules\angular-tree-component\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js'

Tags: angular, lodash

We are currently using angular-tree-component to display a tree structure dual ListBox.with ng serve everything works fine, problems start when packaging and adding the library to another project: Throws warning

> 'defaultsDeep' is not exported by 'node_modules\angular-tree-component\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js'

while packaging and on page load in another project, every instance of 'defaultsdeep' function is replaced by undefined.

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "ap-example-component-library",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
  },
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "^7.0.1",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.5.0",
    "ap-agency-component-library": "0.0.29",
    "ap-company-component-library": "0.0.25",
    "ap-office-component-library": "0.0.24",
    "ap-shared-service-library": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^0.9.9",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29",
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^1.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3",
    "lodash": "4.17.5"
  }
}
```

ng- packagr.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
    "lib": {
             "entryFile": "public_api.ts"

     }
}
```

We are using Angular 5.Have tried couple of options like importing lodash as dev dependency, adding external in ng-package.json:lib section, installing loadash specific module and few others.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** We'd tried all those too, going from our original:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'
```

**Symptom:** We inspected the generated es5 bundles and our code was getting transpiled to

```
import { chain, omit, pick, slice } from 'lodash';
```

and hence the error.

**Solution:** We changed the import to a *require* and everything sorted itself out:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
```

Comment: and in which file did you make this change ? in `component.ts` files ?

Comment: in whichever file where you're using lodash